# Why does 'top | grep > file' not work?

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

I tested the following command, but it doesn't work.

```
$> top -b -d 1 | grep java > top.log
```

It doesn't use standard error. I checked that it uses standard output, but top.log is always empty. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think top is "interactive" and does not have a typical standard output stream. So grep isn't getting the input perhaps.

Comment: Is Java actually running and taking enough resources to show up?

Comment: Judging by the [man page](http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml), the options you're passing to `top` seem redundant.

Comment: @squiguy '-b' option makes it batch mode. In fact, just only top redirection to file works. And top | grep something also works in display.

Comment: @user2357112 Absolutely positive. Java is just example. Try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Windows, so I can't experiment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) rather than `top`? `ps` also lets you specify exactly what information to output.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By default, `grep` buffers output which implies that nothing would be written to `top.log` until the `grep` output exceeds the size of the buffer (which might vary across systems).

Tell `grep` to use line buffering on output.  Try:

```
top -b -d 1 | grep --line-buffered java > top.log
```

Comment: Shouldn't `grep` flush its output when `top` exits? With `-d 1`, it looks like that should happen immediately.

Comment: @user2357112 Only if it would exit!

Comment: ...it doesn't exit? There must be something seriously wrong with my mental model somewhere.

Comment: @user2357112: maybe you're thinking of `-n 1` (1 iteration) instead of `-d 1` (1 sec interval).

Comment: @PeterCordes: That was probably it.

Answer (score 2):

In my embedded machine, grep hadn't the --line-buffered option. So I used this workaround for my myself:

```
while :;do top -b -n 1 | grep java >> top.log;done &
```

By this way I could have a running monitor in the background for a program like "java" and keep all results in the file top.log.